# Controlling the discriminant size of a polynomial using roots

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, discriminant

I'm trying to generate random monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ whose absolute discriminant is within a certain size range (say $10^t$, where $t$ is a positive integer).
I also need to be able fix the number of real and complex roots.
Does anyone know an effective strategy to do this?

My current strategy for fixed degree $n$ is to use the formula
$$|D| = \prod_{i < j}(r_i - r_j)^2$$
where $r_1, \ldots r_n$ are the roots of the polynomial.

At a glance, we can divide the terms of the product into 3 groups,

- those that are the difference of reals, $R_1$,
- those that are differences of complex numbers and their conjugates ($z - \bar{z}$), $R_2$,
- and those that are differences of reals and complex numbers or differences of non-conjugate complex numbers $R_3$.

I'm trying to preselect the roots in $\mathbb{C}$ such that their differences are within a certain range (supposing there are $s$ terms in the product, one might choose them to be around $10^{t/2s})$ which works well for the totally real case, but the presence of complex roots makes things harder.

It's simple enough to control the terms of $R_1$ and $R_2$, but the terms in $R_3$ seem hard to intelligently bound in this way. If anyone has ideas they would be very appreciated!

Comment: Pair the terms in $R_3$ up with their conjugates?

Comment: Ah yes that's a good suggestion. I left out some details about bounding norms of the differences of the elements (which allows for your suggestion of pairing up conjugates). It is not clear to me though how to choose the complex and real parts of the roots so that I can control the norm of the difference for each possible pair along with norm of the root itself.